# Substring error on the condition 'WHERE' CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have data where the data contained my ID to make keywords, I tried to separate the ID and took the 4-digit sample ID "PRNE4" but after I tried to make the script there is an error displayed? What is wrong?

My link

> http://localhost/project/profile/get/PRNE

error

> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

My Smple ID

```
PRNE1
PRNE2
```

Controllers

```
public function Index($) {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array (
                   'profile' => $this->M_model->get_profile($id));
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

Models

```
function get_profile($id) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('tb_sample')
                      ->where("(SUBSTRING(id_sample, 0, 4) = '$id')")
                      ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }   
}
```

Views

```
<?php
   $no = 1;
    foreach ($profile as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo  '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
        echo  '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
        echo  '<td>'.$row->profile.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
    $no++;  
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) doc says

> For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in
>   the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as
>   1.

```
->where("(SUBSTRING(id_sample, 1, 4) = '$id')")
```

So the first position is 1, not 0.

Also in your model, if the result of the query is empty there is no return from the get_profile function. You can can return `$query` as suggested in other answer and use the object in the view, or return an empty array at the end of the function if you want to keep your format:

```
function get_profile($id) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('tb_sample')
                      ->where("(SUBSTRING(id_sample, 1, 4) = '$id')")
                      ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
    return array();  
}
```

Comment: thanks @phobia82, yes ID data that have 5 characters, but which will be used as a keyword such as uri-> segment, so I took the 4 characters of the database separated by substring... ID =`PRNE1`  , I expect it = `PRNE`

Comment: Oh, got it, in SUBSTRING, the first position is 1, not 0, updating my answer now

Comment: hahahaha SOLVED .... it was just her problem, why not begin from `0` because all this time I make use `0` as the first value in the substring, whether the use of different substring mysql and php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In Controller

```
public function index() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['profile'] = $this->M_model->get_profile($id);
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

In Model

```
function get_profile($id) {
    $this->db->select('*')
    $this->db->from('tb_sample')
    $this->db->where("(SUBSTRING(id_sample, 5) = '$id')") // if PRNE4 => 4 (cut the string start for pos of 5)

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

In View

```
<?php
   $no = 1;
    foreach ($profile->result() as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo  '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
        echo  '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
        echo  '<td>'.$row->profile.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';   
        $no++;  
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Soe Chit Kaung, after I try scripts you get an error when I, add '$' on the index (), I delete it after the '$' is not an error but the data is not found.

Comment: Hey. @irwan dwiyanto, I hav edited the code. try again. If still data not found. just comment `where` line and see if there is data.